# div inside select tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">

    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <label for="class_code_reservation">Class Code</label>
      <select type="text" class="form-control" id="class_code_reservation" name="class_code_resevation" autocomplete="off">
        <div id="classdata"></div>
      </select>
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <a href="class_list_form.php" target="_blank"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> view class list</a>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
include "connect_database.php";
$course =$_POST['course'];
$fetchquery = "SELECT * FROM `class` WHERE course = '$course'";
$fetch = mysqli_query($conn, $fetchquery);
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch)) {
    echo "<option value=".$rows['class_code']." >".$rows['class_code']."      </option>";
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function classcode() {
  var course = $('#course_reservation').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "reservation_class_code.php",
    data: "course=" + course
  }).done(function(data) {
    alert(data)
    $('#classdata').html(data);
  });
}
```

I want to populate dropdown option depending on what the user will choose using ajax but dreamweaver highlights div with an id of classdata as an error.

Comment: What dreamweaver does doesn't matter, it is a text editor. You should append to the `select` each `option`. You need to correct the quoting on those attribute as well because currently your quotes are for PHP strings encapsulation. You also are open to SQL injections with this code..

Comment: You should learn proper html syntax. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select Select's can't have div's as direct descendants.

Comment: `<div>` is not a valid child of `<select>`. That's probably what your IDE is trying to tell you. Browsers will just kick it out of there and put it somewhere nearby. Also `<option>` is not valid child of `<div>` either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify your ajax call as below

```
function classcode() {
  var course = $('#course_reservation').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "reservation_class_code.php",
    data: "course=" + course
  }).done(function(data) {
    $('#class_code_reservation').html(data);
  });
}
```

And remove the `<div id="classdata"></div>` from your HTML

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using div tags inside the select. Use option tags instead.

```
<option>Example</option>
<option>Example1</option>
```

Comment: but i want to have an option depending on what the user will choose..read my code

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code instead :

```
$.post('reservation_class_code.php', {course: course}, function( data ) {
     $('#class_code_reservation').html(data);
});
```

That will send a post request with parameter course and append the result data to ul tag `class_code_reservation`.

Hope this helps.